# Returing a valid self object from a class member function is evaluated as None in caller method

Tags: python, oop

'''
Simple map ADT implementation using BST
'''

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import os

class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, key, data, left, right, parent):
        self.key = key
        self.value = data
        self.leftchild = left
        self.rightchild = right
        self.parent = parent

    def insertnode(self, key, value):
        if key <= self.key:
            #left child
            if self.leftchild is not None:
                self.leftchild.insertnode(key, value)
            else:
                self.leftchild = TreeNode(key=key, data=value, left=None, right=None, parent=self)
        else:
            if self.rightchild is not None:
                self.rightchild.insertnode(key, value)
            else:
                self.rightchild = TreeNode(key=key, data=value, left=None, right=None, parent=self)

    def displaynode(self):
        if self.key is not None:
            print(self.key, ":", self.value)
            if self.leftchild is not None:
                self.leftchild.displaynode()
            if self.rightchild is not None:
                self.rightchild.displaynode()

    def search(self, key):
        if self is None:
            return None
        elif key == self.key:
            return self
        elif key < self.key:
            self.leftchild.search(key)
        else:
            self.rightchild.search(key)

    def deletekey(self, key):
        keyNode = self.search(key)
        print(keyNode)
        if keyNode is None:
            raise KeyError('Key not found in the tree.')
        else:
            if keyNode.leftchild is None and keyNode.rightchild is None:
                keyNode = None
            elif keyNode.leftchild is not None and keyNode.rightchild is not None:
                if keyNode.parent is None:
                    self.root = keyNode.leftchild
                else:
                    keyNode.rightchild.parent = keyNode.leftchild
                    keyNode.parent.leftchild = keyNode.leftchild
                keyNode = None
            elif keyNode.leftchild is not None:
                keyNode.parent.leftchild = keyNode.leftchild
                keyNode = None
            elif keyNode.rightchild is not None:
                keyNode.parent.leftchild = keyNode.rightchild
                keyNode = None
        return True


class binaryTree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def length(self):
        return self.size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def insert(self, key, value):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = TreeNode(key=key, data=value, left=None, right=None, parent=self)
            self.size = self.size + 1
        else:
            self.root.insertnode(key, value)
            self.size = self.size + 1

    def display(self):
        if self.root is None:
            return None
        else:
            #currentNode = self.root
            self.root.displaynode()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.root.insertnode(key, value)
        self.size = self.size + 1

    def __contains__(self, item):
        if self.root.search(item) is not None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def find(self, key):
        if self.root.search(key) is not None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if self.root.deletekey(key, self.root):
            self.size = self.size - 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tree = binaryTree()
    tree.insert(100, 'a')
    tree.insert(50, 'b')
    tree.insert(200, 'c')
    #tree.insert(25, 'd')
    tree[25] = 'd'
    print(tree.size)
    tree.display()
    if 50 in tree:
        print(f'{50} found')
    else:
        print(f'{50} not found')

    print(tree.find(50))
    tr = TreeNode(key = 100, data='a', left=None, right=None parent=None)
    print(tr.search(100))
    #del tree[50]
    #tree.display()
```

I am looking for key 50 in the tree by overriding the 'in' using **contains** and the key is there in the tree which and it returns 'self' object from the search method in the class TreeNode. 
However, when its evaluated in the **contains** or find() in the binary tree class its always None. Not sure what Iam missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're not returning the value of your recursive search in your `TreeNode.search` method, so the final return value will always be None, because those conditional branches don't return any value otherwise (unless the key you're looking for belongs to the first Node you search):

```
def search(self, key):
        if self is None:
            return None
        elif key == self.key:
            return self
        elif key < self.key:
            return self.leftchild.search(key) # need to return this value
        else:
            return self.rightchild.search(key) # need to return this value
```